# Using the RecyclerView example doesn't compile

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am looking into designing my app to work with Android L and designing it to use the new Material Design.

I'm looking into the example of the RecyclerView at https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html but the example doesn't compile.

Below is my activity class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] myDataset = new String[2];
        myDataset[0] = "Hello";
        myDataset[1] = "World";

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recylcer);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Below is my MyAdapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the type of views that you are using
    // (custom viewholder)
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

The problem that I have, when I create the instance of the ViewHolder the example says to pass in the variable `v` which is a View but Android Studio is saying that it expects a TextView.

I'm assuming I've done some wrong as I would like to think that the examples that Google's Android Development Site would have correct code but I can't see for the life of me what I could have got wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, it expects `TextView` because you request `TextView` in the constructor of your ViewHolder static class. Change that to `View`. It might help.

Comment: That's what the Android website says it should be, if I change the constructor to be View then the mTextView cannot be set as this is set via the variable that's passed into the constructor

Comment: ViewHolder constructor just expects a View, not necessarily TextView.
So as Boldizsar suggested, change your constructor to receive a View and cast it there (because you know it is a TextView). Or cast v into TextView before calling your ViewHolder's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the constructor like Boldizsar said, then why don't you try to cast your inflated view as a TextView and create a viewholder with that textview.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
    super(v);
    mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
}
```

R.layout.my_text_view looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```